# Regular expression match using preg match all in php

Tags: php, html, preg-match-all

I have a string like this

```
<a href="http://www.example1.com"><b>12345</b> - John George<br><span>some_text1</span></a>
<a href="http://www.example2.com"><b>67890</b> - George Jerry<br><span>some_text2</span></a>
```

Using preg_match_all (PHP) I want to be able to extract the url, id and name but I`m not figured out the good *sPattern* (see bellow):

```
$sPattern = "/<a href=\"(.*?)\"><b>(.*?)<\/b>\" - (.*?)\"<br>(.*?)/";
preg_match_all($sPattern, $content, $aMatch);
```

Answer (score 2):

I humbly suggest use an HTML Parser like `DOMDocument` instead:

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.example1.com"><b>12345</b> - John George<br><span>some_text1</span></a>
<a href="http://www.example2.com"><b>67890</b> - George Jerry<br><span>some_text2</span></a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$data = array();
foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    $href = $anchor->nodeValue; // get the anchor href
    $b = $anchor->firstChild->nodeValue; // get the b tag value
    $data[] = array('href' => $href, 'id' => $b);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably better if you write a bit more specific patterns, try this one:

```
$sPattern = "/<a href=\"([ˆ"]+)\"><b>(\d+)<\/b> - ((\w+ )*\w+)<br><span>([^<]+)<\/span><\/a>/";
```

Comment: I tried a pattern like this: "/<a href=\"(.*?)\"><b>(.*?)<\/b> - (\w+)/" It works fine but with a little exception: if I have names like 'Tom-Jerry' or 'Tom & Jerry' returns only the first word (e.g. 'Tom')

Comment: I see, then you have to change the last bracket, probably the best way to change it is to ([^<]+). That would select everything to the </span> element. The only problem would be if there were another element inside the span, something like <span>Tom & <b>Jerry</b></span>